# Determining complexity of algorithm

Tags: python, big-o

So I was given this question. Read the text descriptions of the algorithms below. For each algorithm, explain which of the following complexity classes best describe the worst-case time performance for a list of n.

Given a list L of floats, and an integer 0 <= i < len(L) - 1, return True if the ith element of L is less than the (i + 1)th element of L. Explain what behaviour an implementation of each algorithm should exhibit when run on a list of size 2n versus a list of size n.

So out of a guess I assumed the complexity for this is O(1). I don't understand the behaviour of the implementation when run on a list of size 2n versus a list of size n

Comment: Do you have any examples of code you've already tried at all?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter there was no code provided just this explanation

Comment: What if your list was implemented as a linked list? What if it was implemented as a binary tree? Unless you know how the list stores its elements, you cannot know the time complexity.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: This is not a task that would involve writing any code.

Comment: @AndyG Uhh this was a question from a handout. It wasn't meant to be overcomplicated just simply pick the complexity from O(1), O(log n), O(n), O(n logn), O(n2). Then the question below

Comment: I assumed if the question was posted on Stack Overflow the intention was to write computer code in order to solve it. If not it wants to be on Math Stack Exchange...?

Comment: @AndyG: Given the Python tag and the use of Python syntax, it seems reasonable to interpret "list" as referring to an ordinary Python list.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: This would not be an on-topic question for Math.SE.

Comment: Anyone care to share their thoughts on the question?

Comment: So, the mathematical element could be solved without the use of computer code but is coding related... I can see the case for inclusion in that eventuality but it's touch and go. How would @user2357112 suggest solving it?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: Solving the question or deciding where to put it? You could make a case for http://cs.stackexchange.com; algorithmic analysis is more on topic there, but we're talking about a specific programming language, and the fact that it's on topic there doesn't mean it's not on topic here.

Comment: Up to you. I was suggesting that if the question can either be solved with computer code, or is a question that might have an application to coding in future it should probably be on topic. If not it probably needs moving. Of course I'd rather see it solved with computer code. Or it be solved in another way and shown to be applicable to the coding community in the process.  If you algorithm significantly I would gladly step aside, remove my objection and allow you to show a solution that is of direct interest to the coding community.

Answer (score 0):

> So out of a guess I assumed the complexity for this is O(1). I don't
>   understand the behaviour of the implementation when run on a list of
>   size 2n versus a list of size n

O(1) means the algorithm takes one constant time over any size of data. Accessing element of an array is a typical example.

In Python, list is not array data structure. Dictionary probably has O(1) because it uses Hash table.